# VS Code split terminal issues with Powershell only

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

In VS Code anytime I try to "split" my PowerShell terminal it gives me this issue:

[image]

My default terminal is PowerShell, and this only happens if the first terminal instance is PowerShell. So for example, I can split a terminal between git bash and PowerShell if I select the git bash terminal and split it like so:

[image]

I'm pretty sure the issue is the double quotes around my path:

> ""C:\Users\Austin Lee"" does not exist.

I tried switching the starting directory with `terminal.integrated.cwd = ""` in my settings.json based on an answer I had seen somewhere, but that didn't fix it. I'm willing to uninstall and reinstall VS Code, but I'm not sure this would fix the issue. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

I've pasted my settings.json from VS code for reference. Also, I don't know if it matters, but I am using Oh My Posh on PowerShell for theming and terminal icons, but I could split a terminal before, so I'm not really sure when this problem started or if an extension is messing it up. I disabled all installed extensions and the issue is still happening.

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Hasklug Nerd Font",
  "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "prettier.semi": false,
  "typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "double",
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula",
  "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
    "172.105.135.48": "linux"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "Ubuntu (WSL)": {
      "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
      "args": [
        "-d",
        "Ubuntu"
      ]
    },
    "Windows PowerShell": {
      "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
    }
  },
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/bin": true,
    "**/obj": true
  },
  "explorer.compactFolders": false,
  "[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
  },
  "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
  "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": true
}
```

Comment: I believe the name of the setting is actually `powershell.cwd` not `terminal.integrated.cwd`.

Comment: I tried that as well and was running into the same issue unfrtounately. Wound up just switching to wsl, using  Ubuntu 22.04, zsh, and oh my posh and no issues so far. Not really sure what happened there with Powershell

Answer (score 1):

Change the following setting to `initial`. This fixed my problem with git bash on VS Code.

`Terminal › Integrated: Split Cwd`

[image: vscode terminal settings]